# grails tag library question

Tags: java, grails

I am using Grails in an application that allows the inline editing of data in a data grid. There are certain key fields that may be defined and should not be editable. Here is some example code from the tag lib that I am using

```
case "dropdown":
            out << "<select id='"+prefix + id+"' name='" + fieldData.code + "'>"
            out << "<option value=''/>"
            def vals = fieldData.value.split(",")
            vals.each() {
                out << "<option "+ (value == it ? "selected" : "") +" value='" + it + "'>" + it + "</option>"
            }
            out << "</select>"
            break
```

Basically I need to add a class to the form element so that when it renders I can disable it using jQuery. Do I need an if statement for each form control or is there another way to accomplish this with Grails?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You mention that your application allows inline editing of data, but then your code is showing a select list with nothing editable in site.  You say you want to disable it using jQuery.  It looks like you're already assigning an id to your fields which would provide a way to identify them and manipulate their attributes through JQuery.  Can you provide a little more detail around the exact problem you're hoping to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a class="disableMe" or data-type="xyz" and do either a

jQuery(".disableMe").attr("disabled","disabled");

or

jQuery("[data-type='xyz'].attr("disabled","disabled");

Something like that should get you what you are looking for. I don't think the problem you are trying to solve has to do with Grails specifically.